# VS2013 do not create a min.css

Tags: css, less, visual-studio-2013, minify

I have a LESS file that when saved ONLY updates the non-minified css file. No matter what I do it will not update the min file. I can of course minify the main via web essentials, but that sort of negates the function of compiling LESS on save...

There is no error or anything - it just happily ignores the min.css file. In VS2012 it works perfectly.

Does anyone have any idea of what to do about this?

/Erik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done via setting: Tools -> Options -> Web Essentials -> LESS.
I found the answer here - [How to ignore certain LESS files in Web Essentials LESS compiling? (Bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213067/how-to-ignore-certain-less-files-in-web-essentials-less-compiling-bootstrap)

Update:
This option must be set on CSS, see screenshot:
[image]

After this when you save LESS it will create a .min.css file too.

Comment: Thank you - I was going mad!