# How to reference global variables in modular LESS files?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, less, web-essentials

How can I reference a variable defined in a central variables.less file in an individual module.less file, when the module does not directly reference variables.less?

Here's the structure of my Styles folder:

```
Styles
  _variables.less
  Site.less

  Modules
    _forms.less
    _navbar-top.less
    _panels.less
    _titlebar.less
    Modules.less

  Pages
    _page1.less
    _page2.less
    Pages.less
```

The file Site.less basically looks like this:

```
@import "_variables.less";
@import "Modules/Modules.less";
@import "Pages/Pages.less";
```

(it only includes capitalized LESS files)

And Modules.less looks like:

```
@import "_forms.less";
@import "_navbar-top.less";
@import "_panels.less";
@import "_titlebar.less";
```

(it only includes underscore-prefixed files in the same folder)

Pages.less is structured the same way.

What I want to do is have the following in the Modules/_panels.less file:

```
.panel-form {
    .panel-variant(1px; @text-color; @component-default-bg; 1px);
    border-top: solid darken(@component-default-bg, 1px);
    border-bottom: solid darken(@component-default-bg, 1px);
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
```

But of course my LESS compiler (Visual Studio Web Essentials 2013.5) is throwing an error and refusing to compile the file _panels.less because it is referencing a variable that does not exist in *its* scope.

Currently my workaround is to declare .panel-form in Site.css but that is a hack -- I don't want to start declaring an arbitrary number of modules there.

Is it possible to reference a variable like this and still compile to CSS, and if so how? If not, is there a better structure I should use?

Incidentally I noticed that the LESS compiler doesn't like Bootstrap either, because it raises errors if I type a single space into a Bootstrap LESS file e.g. navbar.less and try to save it, reporting that (for navbar.less) the mixin `.clearfix()` is undefined. Which of course it is, because navbar.less does not reference mixins.less, yet if it can compile from bootstrap.less downward then everything will work just fine...

Comment: What you need is to configure the WE to compile the project master file and not the file you edit/save. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213067.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks, but I don't see anything in that answer about compiling a master file. There are references to WE ignoring files with a leading underscore by convention. So I'm guessing maybe I should change the files like Modules.css to _modules.css or similar so it doesn't try to compile. Will try that tomorrow morning. Or did I miss something? How do I configure it the way you mention? Thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19213447

Comment: @seven-phases-max Ok yes my apologies I saw that but your answer read as if there were a way to "point" WE at a single master LESS file. I just made that change in WE but it is still compiling underscore-prefixed LESS files to CSS and throwing errors. The errors don't stop it from building but they are reporting errors in the Error List window. From what I read the underscore prefix is supposed to prevent WE from compiling the LESS file, yet it is still compiling. Am I missing a setting somewhere? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, renaming the Modules/Modules.less file to Modules/__Modules.less (2 underscores so it sorts to the top) seems to solve the issue. It still throws errors and litters the Error List but the styles I define in Modules/_panels.less using the variables from ./_variables.less actually compiles properly into ./Site.css on build. Wish there was some way to turn off the errors but at least it works. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your environment but with triple slash directives it usually works:

- root
- less
- - - _vars.less
- - - modules
- - - - someModule.less

Inside "someModule.less" you should try this:

```
/// <reference path="../_variables.less" />
```